# Copy files from container to host while inside the container

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm working on automation pipeline using Kubernetes and Jenkins. All my commands are running from inside the jnlp-slave container. The jnlp-slave is deployed onto a worker node by Kubernetes. I have -v /var/run/docker.sock on my jnlp-slave so it can run docker commands from inside the container.

***Issue:***

I'm trying to copy files inside the jnlp-slave container to the host machine (worker node), but the command below does not copy files to host machine, but to destination of the container itself:

```
docker cp <container_id>:/home/jenkins/workspace /home/jenkins/workspace
```

---

*Clarification*:

Since the container is executing the command, files located inside the container is copied to the destination path which is also inside the container.

Normally, docker commands are executed on the host machine. Therefore, the `docker cp` can be used to copy files from container to host and from host to container. But in this case, the `docker cp` is executed from inside the container.

---

How can I make the container to copy files to the host machine without running docker commands on the host? Is there a command which the container can run to copy files to the host?

P.S. I've tried mounting volume on the host. But the files only can be shared from the host to the container and not the other way around. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: don't delete the old question to ask the same question again

Comment: Sorry, but you've falsely marked my question as a duplicate. I've revised my question but it's already closed.

Comment: You should have commented that in the previous question and I would have reopened it..deleting and asking same question may lead to question ban

Comment: My apologies, I will keep that in mind. I don't post frequently.

Comment: You want to use Docker, to copy files out of a Kubernetes pod, on to a random host filesystem somewhere in the cluster?  You might redesign this either to push the file out to somewhere known or to pull the file out of the pod, without specifically involving one of the host filesystems.

Comment: @DavidMaze The reason I want to copy files onto the host (worker node) is because there are other containers within the same pod trying to access the files. The thing is I already have a successful pipeline that doesn't rely on Kubernetes (Jenkins pipeline running on the host machine). Now, I'm trying to covert that pipeline to work with Kubernetes. I guess I need to change the other containers to work differently. Anyway, thanks for your advice!

Comment: An `emptyDir` volume can share files between containers in the same pod.  I would look at trying to re-engineer this, though; multiple containers in the same pod is also usually discouraged.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've tried using an `emptyDir` volume by adding it in Jenkins' Kubernetes configuration, but the host's directory overwrites the _jnlp-slave_ container's directory. I have managed to find a solution to allow other containers within the same pod to access the files in _jnlp-slave_. What I did was copy the files from _jnlp-slave_ container to the other containers. Now, I've learned to not copy files from containers onto the worker node on Kubernetes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you should probably redesign entirely your solution.

But let's summarize what you currently have and try to figure out what you can do with it and not make your solution even more complicated at the same time.

> What I did was copy the files from jnlp-slave container to the other
> containers.

Copying files from one container to all others is a bit an overkill (btw. How many of them do you place in one `Pod` ?)

Maybe your containers don't have to be deployed withing the same `Pod` ? If for some reason this is currently impossible, maybe at least the content of the `/home/jenkins/workspace` directory shouldn't be integral part of your docker image as it is now ? If this is also impossible, you have no other remedy than to copy somehow those files from the original container based on that image to the shared location which is also available for other containers existing within the same `Pod`.

[emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir), mentioned in comments might be an option allowing you to achieve it. However keep in mind that the data stored in an `emptyDir` volume is not persistent in any way and is deleted along with the deletion of the pod. If you're ok with this fact, it may be a solution for you.

If your data is originally part of your image, it should be first transferred to your `emptyDir` volume as by its very definition it is initially empty. Simply mounting it under `/home/jenkins/workspace` won't make the data originally available in this directory in your container automagically appear in the `emptyDir` volume. From the moment you mount your `emptyDir` under `/home/jenkins/workspace` it will contain the content of `emptyDir` i.e. nothing.

Therefore you need to pre-populate it somehow and one of the available solutions to do that is using an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). As your data is originally the integral part of your docker image, you must use the same image also for the `initContainer`.

Your deployment may look similar to the one below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: pre-populate-empty-dir
        image: <image-1>
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp -a /home/jenkins/workspace/* /mnt/empty-dir-content/']
        volumeMounts:
         - name: cache-volume
           mountPath: "/mnt/empty-dir-content/"
      containers:
      - name: app-container-1
        image: <image-1>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cache-volume
            mountPath: "/home/jenkins/workspace"
      - name: app-container-2
        image: <image-2>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8082
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cache-volume
            mountPath: "/home/jenkins/workspace"
      - name: app-container-3
        image: <image-3>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8083
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cache-volume
            mountPath: "/home/jenkins/workspace"
      volumes:
      - name: cache-volume
        emptyDir: {}
```

Once your data has been copied to an `emptyDir` volume by the `initContainer`, it will be available for all the main `containers` and can be mounted under the same path by each of them.